# Connect Azure Database through docker windows container

Tags: sql-server, azure, docker, .net-4.8, windows-container

I have a **.netframework 4.7.2 application with the azure database**. I have created a docker windows container for this application. When I launch this application in the Docker container on my local machine, it gives an error:

[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (**provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server**)]

**ConnectionString**:
connectionString="Data Source=tcp:servername.database.windows.net,1433;Database=databasename;User ID=testuser;Password=testpassword;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

**Docker File:**

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

ARG source

WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot

COPY ./bin/Release/Publish/ .

My IP Address is already added in the azure database and when I connect through the SQL management studio from the local machine it works without any issue. Also, It works fine
with visual studio.

I believe my docker has internet access. When I ping google.com inside the docker container, it returns the result
[ping google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAgfN.png)

C:\inetpub\wwwroot>ping google.com

Pinging google.com [172.217.166.14] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 172.217.166.14: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=118

Reply from 172.217.166.14: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=118

Reply from 172.217.166.14: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=118

Reply from 172.217.166.14: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=118

Ping statistics for 172.217.166.14:

```
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
```

Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:

```
Minimum = 19ms, Maximum = 19ms, Average = 19ms
```

C:\inetpub\wwwroot>

Can someone guide me on how can I connect my application to the Azure database inside the docker container?

Comment: I don't think the error message is coming from a piece of code that uses that connection string. `provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server` does not correlate with use of the TCP driver (not Named Pipes) in `Data Source=tcp:anyServerNameOrIpAddress;`

Comment: Aside... to make use of Azure SQL instances on `database.windows.net`, in particular Azure-based authentication mechanisms, you'll probably want to switch from the legacy `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace and classes to the modern and better-supported `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` namespace and classes.

Comment: I checked the stack trace, the error occured at the following line:  WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("connectionstringName", "Databasename", "Id", "Name", autoCreateTables: false);

I will try with "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" and will update you, but on my local machine (visual studio), the code is working with "System.Data.SqlClient"

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.